# Mark on passport right next to my Chinese visa

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, damaged-passports

My two year old child put a mark in my passport on the page next to the page containing my Chinese visa. Is it going to cause me any issues?

Here is the double page image – I verified there is no mark on the visa page:
[image]

Comment: What kind of mark? What was used (crayon, pencil, pen, etc)? Maybe share a picture (with identifying info blocked out) to show how bad it is.

Comment: can you please check the link i added now @FreeMan

Comment: The mark appears to be at the bottom of a page. How is "right in front" of the visa?

Comment: @AndrewLeach sorry for the confusion, i mean opposite to the page of the visa

Comment: I would suggest you alter the image to show the double-page spread, the right way up. Don't forget to block out personally-identifying information. I think you should be able to add the image directly to the post, too (but if not, someone else can).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While technically you're not supposed to alter a passport in any way, since the scribbles are on an empty page and clearly have no meaning, **you should be fine**.

Answer (score 3):

I am answering my own question just in case anyone else face similar issue in the future. I had no issue at immigration for entry and exit stamps.